# Condition that linear map applied to basis vectors still yield a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T\in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ where $\dim V=\dim W=n$. If the list of vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ forms a basis of $V$. What's the condition that must be satisified such that the list $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n$ forms a basis of $W$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\textsf T$ is an isomorphism we're done. In this case, since $\dim V=\dim W$, injectivity is equivalent to surjectivity. So, just we need that one of the two be fulfilled.

Comment: Okay... I just asked this out of curiosity. We haven’t studied isomorphism of linear maps yet.

Comment: An isomorphism between vector spaces is simply a linear map which is invertible (or a bijection).

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: Your welcome! The equivalence between inyectivity and surjectivity is also clear?

Answer (score 0):

In general, not restricting to finite dimension or to $V$ and $W$ having equal dimension, we have:

> **Theorem.** Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, and let $T\colon V\to W$ be a linear transformation.
>
> 1. If $B\subset V$ and the multiset $T(B)=\{T(x)\mid x\in B\}$ is linearly independent, then $B$ is linearly independent.
> 2. $T$ is one-to-one if and only if for every subset $B$ of $V$,  if $B$ is linearly independent, then $T(B) = \{T(x)\mid x\in B\}$ is linearly independent.
> 3. $T$ is onto if and only if for every subset $S$ of $V$, if $S$ spans $V$ then $T(S)=\{T(x)\mid x\in S\}$ spans $W$.

*Proof.*

1. We may assume that $T$ is one-to-one on $B$, since otherwise the multiset $T(B)$ has repeated vectors and hence is linearly dependent. Let $b_1,\ldots,b_n\in B$ and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ be scalars such that $\alpha_1b_1+\cdots+\alpha_nb_n = \mathbf{0}$. Then $\mathbf{0}=T(\alpha_1b_1+\cdots + \alpha_nb_n) = \alpha_1T(b_1)+\cdots+\alpha_nT(b_n)$. Since $T(B)$ is linearly independent, this implies $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n=0$. Thus, $B$ is linearly independent, as claimed.
2. If $T$ is not one-to-one, then let $v\in \mathrm{ker}(T)$ be nonzero. Then $B=\{v\}$ is linearly independent, but $T(B) = \{\mathbf{0}\}$ is not. Conversely, if $T$ is one-to-one, and $B$ is linearly independent, then let $b_1,\ldots,b_n\in B$ and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ be scalars such that $\alpha_1T(b_1)+\cdots + \alpha_nT(b_n) = \mathbf{0}$. Then $T(\alpha_1b_1+\cdots+\alpha_nb_n) = \mathbf{0}$, but since $T$ is one-to-one, this means that $\alpha_1b_1+\cdots+\alpha_nb_n=\mathbf{0}$. Since $B$ is linearly independent, this implies that $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n = 0$. Thus, $T(B)$ is linearly independent.
3. We know that if $S$ spans $V$, then $T(S)$ spans $T(V)$. If $T$ is onto, and $S$ spans $V$, then $T(S)$ spans $T(V)=W$. Conversely, if whenever $S$ spans $V$ we have that $T(S)$ spans $W$, then since $V$ spans itself, $T(V)$ spans $W$. But $T(V)=\mathrm{Im}(T)$, so $T(V)$ is already a subspace, hence $T(V) = \mathrm{span}(T(V)) = W$. Thus, $T$ is onto. $\Box$

From the above, we obtain:

**Corollary.** Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, and let $T\colon V\to W$ be a linear transformation. Then $T$ sends bases of $V$ to bases of $W$ if and only if $T$ is an isomorphism.

*Proof.* If $T$ sends bases of $V$ to bases of $W$, then it sends linearly independent sets to linearly independent sets: take a linearly independent set $I$, extend it to a basis $B$; then $T(B)$ is a basis, hence linearly independent, and $T(I)$ is a subset of a linearly independent set and therefore linearly independent. Thus, $T$ is one-to-one by the Theorem. And $T$ sends spanning sets to spanning sets: if $S$ is a spanning set, then it contains a basis $B$; then $T(B)$ is a basis, hence spans $W$, and so $T(S)$ is a set containing a spanning set, and therefore $T(S)$ spans. Since $T$ sends spanning sets to spanning sets, it follows that $T$ is onto. Thus, $T$ is one-to-one and onto, and hence an isomorphism.

Conversely, if $T$ is an isomorphism, and $B$ is a basis for $V$, then $T(B)$ is linearly independent because $T$ is one-to-one and $B$ is linearly independents; and $T(B)$ spans $W$ because $B$ spans $W$ and $T$ is surjective. Hence $T(B)$ is a linearly independent spanning set, hence a basis. So $T$ sends bases of $V$ to bases of $W$, as claimed. $\Box$